# Not able to locate an element within the IFrame (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests

So i have create successful test of adding a card to my profile and now i would like ot verify if card was added so i would like to check if "Your card was successfully added" text appeared, however for some kind of a reason the className not located.

This is an iframe however i do enter it to add the card details and submit them, so trying to understand why it cant locate the follow:

[image]

Adding card

```
public void addCard(Card card) {
        switchToCardIframe()
                .fillInCardNumber(card.getCardNumber())
                .fillInCardHolder(card.getCardHolderName())
                .fillInExpiryDate(card.getExpiryDate())
                .fillInCvv(card.getCvv())
                .clickOnToggle()
                .clickOnAddButton();
    }
```

This is how i locate the text

```
@FindBy(css = "payment-state-message")
private WebElement cardAddedIndicator;
```

Test

```
@Test
public void shouldSuccessfullyAddCard() {
    myCards.addCard(cardData());
    assertTrue(myCards.getCardAddedIndicator().isDisplayed());
}
```

I have also tried to check if another element displayed by escaping the iframe but no luck so any help appreciated

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent()
```

[image]

I have also attempted Thread.sleep() for 10 seconds before taking getting the text from the css locater but not luck

Here is the base page where wait initialized

```
public class BasePage {

    public WebDriver driver;
    protected Wait wait;

    public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
        initializePage(driver);
        this.wait = new Wait(driver);
    }

    final protected void initializePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 20), this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css is wrong, so instead of

```
@FindBy(css = "payment-state-message")
private WebElement cardAddedIndicator;
```

try this

```
@FindBy(css = ".payment-state-message")
private WebElement cardAddedIndicator;
```

also do not check for visibility by `.isDisplay`

rather have a text method called on it. Put some delay/wait as well.

```
String actualMessage = myCards.getCardAddedIndicator().getText();
String expectedMessage = "Your card was successfully added"
```

then assert these two based on their actual and expected behavior .

Comment: sadly that isnt the case and i get an exception

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".payment-state-message"}

Comment: please put a wait of 5 seconds, initially hardcoded and then use `div.payment-state-message`

Comment: hey man ,i tried it no luck , added additional code for you to have a look, thank you for your help buddy

Comment: first thing that you should verify if the `addCard` element and `cardAddedIndicator` both are in same or different iframe  ? please check that and let me know

Answer (score 0):

**Conclusion** :

When there is an `iframe` form and you submit it, it does not mean that its still the same `iframe`. In my case when I submitted the form then `iframe` disappeared however in order for for the element to be located I had to perform `driver().switch().parentFrame()`

**FYI**: First always check your locators and make sure they are right.